# Why is Option<T>::and_then() not mutually exclusive from a following .unwrap_or()?

Tags: rust, option-type

Why is it that Option::and_then() doesn't process exclusively from a following Option::unwrap_or()? Shouldn't the and_then() only happen if the Option is a Some() and then the .unwrap_or() only happens if the Option is a None? Here's a code example, the first method triggers a complaint from the borrow checker, and the later method does not, but theoretically shouldn't they be doing the same thing?

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Response {
    account: String,
    status: String,
    error: String,
}

fn main() {

    let num = String::from("426238");
    let record = {
        Response {
            account: "".into(),
            status: "failed".into(),
            error: "Invalid Account".into(),
        }
    };
    let mut acct_map = HashMap::new();
    acct_map.insert(&num, record);
    
    // Doesn't work
    let record = acct_map.remove(&num)
    .and_then(|mut r| {r.account = num; Some(r)}) // Should only get processed if there's a Some()
    .unwrap_or( // Should only get processed if there's a None
        Response {
            account: num,
            status: String::from("failed"),
            error: String::from("The server did not return a response for this account."),
        }
    ); // Yet rustc says variable moved from .and_then()
    
    // Works
    let num = String::from("426238");
    let record = if let Some(mut response) = acct_map.remove(&num) {
        response.account = num;
        response
    } else {
        Response {
            account: num,
            status: String::from("failed"),
            error: String::from("The server did not return a response for this account."),
        }
    };
}
```

After I got that complaint while trying the former, I switched to the later given it is more understandable and actually works, but I'm wondering if there is more behind .and_then() and .unwrap_or() than what my understanding is.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [mre]. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here.

Comment: mcarton says it in his answer, but it's worth stressing: the borrow checker only examines the *signatures* of the functions it invokes, it doesn't look inside them to determine what they do. So even if it *could* prove (say through inlining) that `and_then` and `unwrap_or` were exclusive, it would refrain from doing so. That is intentional, and it allows the implementation to change without affecting the API, at least as long as the signature stays the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of, since you used `unwrap_or` rather than `unwrap_or_else`, the parameter of `unwrap_or` will *always* be executed, which means it will *always* move out `num`.

Second, even if you had used `unwrap_or_else`, nothing in the signature of `and_then` or `unwrap_or_else` tell the borrow checker that these methods are mutually exclusive, therefore in its eyes, both lambdas could execute. This isn't allowed.

`if let` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

The closure used in your `and_then()` captures `num` by value. Although the execution of the `.unwrap_or()` is mutually exclusive with assigning `num` to `r.account`, the variable is still moved into the closure's scope.